# Build against an old glibc with Guix

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, guix

Say that you got a c program, but almost any program will do, and put it in a file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>

int main (void) {
    puts (gnu_get_libc_version ());
    return 0;
}
```

And say that you want to build it against a specific version of glibc, for some reason. My initial attempt at doing this would be to create a Guix environment containing that old version of `glibc` along with `gcc` (and `coreutils` for programs like `ls`).

```bsh
$ guix environment --pure --ad-hoc glibc@2.29 gcc-toolchain coreutils
$ rm a.out && gcc printer.c && ldd a.out && a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd2cd0c000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /gnu/store/jlrfl1ss3b4xjggvajwffa9zppfcxksf-gcc-5.5.0-lib/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fcefd7b6000)
    libc.so.6 => /gnu/store/fa6wj5bxkj5ll1d7292a70knmyl7a0cr-glibc-2.31/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcefd5f9000)
    /gnu/store/fa6wj5bxkj5ll1d7292a70knmyl7a0cr-glibc-2.31/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcefd7d1000)
2.31
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. The resulting program is linked against a newer version of `glibc` than I expected, 2.31 rather than 2.29. But this may be due to `gcc` itself being linked against linked against `glibc` 2.31 and that ends up polluting the environment, so to speak.

```bsh
$ ldd $(which gcc)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff7cfc5000)
    libm.so.6 => /gnu/store/fa6wj5bxkj5ll1d7292a70knmyl7a0cr-glibc-2.31/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff842b93000)
    libc.so.6 => /gnu/store/fa6wj5bxkj5ll1d7292a70knmyl7a0cr-glibc-2.31/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff8429d6000)
    /gnu/store/fa6wj5bxkj5ll1d7292a70knmyl7a0cr-glibc-2.31/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff842cd6000)
```

Where do I go from here? I've tried using older versions of `gcc` packaged in Guix, but they all seem to be built against `glibc` 2.31. I also tried adding `-L /gnu/store/hlsas48h6x7364kcfs8yy6xfksdsffr4-glibc-2.29/lib` to my `gcc`-invocation but to no avail.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a perfect example for using docker? This way you can much more easily isolate the environment.

Comment: If it is a container that you want, you can use the `--container` flag of `guix environment`. But the real answer is that I'm more interested in the "garbage collected heap"-structure of Guix rather than the "layers of filesystems"-structure of Docker. The composability of the former far exceeds the latter. And in a development environment I have encountered a ton of annyances with containers that I'd rather avoid if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, or rather: cbaines on #guix@freenode pointed me towards the function `make-gcc-toolchain` which allowed me to set up the environment I wanted. By placing the following code into a file called `development-environment.scm`:

```lisp
(use-modules (gnu packages base)
             (gnu packages commencement)
             (gnu packages gcc)
             (gnu packages version-control))

(define-public gcc-glibc-2.29-toolchain
  (make-gcc-toolchain gcc glibc-2.29))

(list gcc-glibc-2.29-toolchain git coreutils)
```

and then running `guix environment --pure --ad-hoc --load=development-environment.scm` I was able to build my program using the version of glibc that I wanted:

```sh
$ rm a.out && gcc printer.c && ldd a.out && ./a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff7e17c000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /gnu/store/71rcc4qxfgyzr0qphkh9adjsqsb999zk-gcc-glibc-2.29-7.5.0-lib/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2c8adc9000)
    libc.so.6 => /gnu/store/hlsas48h6x7364kcfs8yy6xfksdsffr4-glibc-2.29/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2c8ac0f000)
    /gnu/store/hlsas48h6x7364kcfs8yy6xfksdsffr4-glibc-2.29/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2c8ade4000)
2.29
```

Hot tip for posterity: put the following in a file called `.envrc`, install the package `direnv` and insert it into your shell rc, and fill it with the following content:

```
use guix --ad-hoc --load=development-environment.scm
```

That way, every time you enter that folder with your shell the development environment will be loaded for you. The right version of glibc/gcc will be run even without the `--pure` flag.